# How to stop an AGI script when other party hangsup

Tags: java, asterisk, terminate, agi

I have a Java program that originates a call to a client and, upon answer, connects it to an extension in the dialplan. That extension in turn runs an AGI script to do some interactions with the client.
If the client keeps the line until the end, everything is perfect. But if he hangsup in the middle, the AGI script continues running. I would like it to stop at the moment the client hangsup.

Here is an extract of the originating java program:

```
OriginateAction originateAction;
ManagerResponse originateResponse;
originateAction=new OriginateAction();
originateAction.setChannel(phoneNumber);
originateAction.setExten("700");
originateAction.setContext("users");
originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));

//connect to Asterisk and login
ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory("localhost","******","******");
managerConnection = factory.createManagerConnection();
managerConnection.login();
//send the originate action and wait for a maximum of 30 seconds to get a response
originateResponse=managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000);
```

An extract from the dialplan

```
exten =>700,1,Agi(agi://localhost/message.agi,${var1},${var2},${var3},${var4}); script to play
```

And an extract from the agi script

```
public void service(AgiRequest arg0, AgiChannel arg1) throws AgiException {
        setVariable("missedSteps","4");
        verbose("  --------------  missed steps: 4 ----------------", 3);
        // Answer the channel and welcome
        answer();
        streamFile("silence/1");
        streamFile("welcome");
        setVariable("missedSteps","3");
        verbose("  --------------  missed steps: 3 ----------------", 3);
        //Read the file
        streamFile(fileName);
        setVariable("missedSteps","2");
        verbose("  --------------  missed steps: 2 ----------------", 3);
            ..........
            ..........
        setVariable("missedSteps","1");
        verbose("  --------------  missed steps: 1 ----------------", 3);
            ..........
            ..........
        setVariable("missedSteps","0");
        verbose("  --------------  missed steps: 0 ----------------", 3);
        //hangup
        hangup();
```

So as you can see I am trying to keep a variable that traces the evolution within the script, and I want to keep that variable to store it in a log of the call. As you can see I have added some verbose commands for debugging, and what I see on the console is that the "missedSteps" variable keeps progressing from 4 to 0 whether the client has hung up or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check CHANNEL(checkhangup) variable.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I couldn't find a CHANNEL hanguped variable in the Asterisk documentation. It did try to create a variable in the Dialplan that is set to 1 whenever the channel is hung up, and that is checked at each critical step of the Agi script. But again it doesn't work. In fact it seems that Asterisk only runs the "h" extension once the AGI script has finished running.

Comment: it called checkhangup now. use "asterisk -rx "core show function CHANNEL"  " to see doc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by accident.
In fact the AGI script does stop upon unsuccessful execution of "streamFile". So I just included a few "streamFile("silence/1")" before each critical step, before updating the tracking variable. The AGI script will stop at reaching that instruction and the variable will not be updated.